# Visual Studio 2017 RC - Prerelease has ended

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I get the following message and cannot proceed to do any other work within Visual Studio 2017 RC : This prerelease has ended. This prerelease has expired. Thank you for your participation. Upgrade to the latest version of this product to keep working without interruption.

Upgrade your prerelease Check for an updated license.

No other options on the screen work. ie. "Upgrade your prerelease" or "Check for an updated license. I currently have a valid MSDN license, so this should not be an issue.

Comment: I would argue that it is relevant as it is an issue that started today and is a HUGE problem for developers.

Comment: "any other work" you need to do in VS2017 RC should also be able to be done in VS2015 RTM.  You do have VS2015 installed as well, right?

Comment: Not any other work if you have leveraged any C# 7 language features in your code.

Comment: Vince, it is quite time consuming to convert a 2017 project to a 2015 project. Microsoft just needs to fix this issue sooner than later. And the trust toward Microsoft has suffered a huge hit today. Although RC, it is production ready.

Comment: @Veve and other close-voters, please familiarize yourselves with the site scope: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and in particular "if your question generally covers…
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a server side bug that Microsoft has now fixed.

See the [Visual Studio Team's response](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/11842/2017-community-edition-this-prerelease-has-expired.html)

Comment: Here's the response from Microsoft: Thank you for your feedback! This issue was a server-side bug and has been fixed. Please click "Check for an updated license" to resolve.

Answer (score 7):

**Update: The VS team has fixed the issue on their end. You do not need to perform these steps, simply check for an updated license.** (I'm leaving this answer up in case there is a regression in the future.)

Install Fiddler and turn on HTTPS decryption. Create an AutoResponder rule that matches:

```
regex:(https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Licensing/ClientRights/VisualStudio.*)prerelease(.*)
```

And replaces with:

```
$1release$2
```

With that rule enabled, check for a license again. You should wind up with a trial license that will last until April.

Fiddler should look similar to this when configured (intercepted requests shown on the left):
[image: Intercepted request]

My HTTPS configuration in `Tools->Telerik Fiddler Options` looks like:

[image: HTTPS Options]

Comment: I was unable to make this work in my copy of VS 2017 RC Enterprise.

Comment: @MichaelMortensen Yeah, I saw your other comment. One of my co-workers did the offline install and his license expires May 2017. As part of the installation, it had him install the license certificate.

Comment: I press the "Check for an updated license" and it responds with, "We could not download a license. Please check your network connection or proxy settings."

Comment: Is it possible to add a screenshot of what your Fiddler AutoResponder tab looks like? Not being too familiar with that, I had to do some trial and error to get it right. That might be what some people's problem was.

Comment: @MichaelMortensen Are you seeing Fiddler intercept the HTTPS request? I've added some screenshots as KyleUp suggested.

Comment: @Fls'Zen that is exactly what I have been doing. Only diff was the Network latency, which I have switched off now. If i sign out and sign in again, I cannot do this without disabling capture from Fiddler, as the line is insecure. "Check for an updated license" points to go.microsoft.com/... and not to the URL specified. Only time i see the URL the responder should interact with, is by signing in :-/

Comment: @MichaelMortensen Hmm, I can sign out and in with Fiddler running. I suspect Fiddler's HTTPS root certificate is not trusted. Go to `Tools->Telerik Fiddler Options->HTTPS` and select `Action->Trust Root Certificate`, then follow the prompts to add the certificate to your trusted roots.

Comment: @Fls'Zen hmm .. you are on to something. The URL is never showed with path segments or querystring parameters, which is the default behavior for HTTPS. I did the Action->Trust Root and followed all the prompts .. still no luck .. but I will mingle a little more. Thank you so far for your help, mate!

Comment: @Fls'Zen heureka! It took a reset of Fiddler certificates, but now it works lile a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelMortensen Awesome!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Fiddler option doesn't work for me. Get the following message "we could not unlock visual studio with the accounts available . please ensure that you have added an account with a valid subscription and the account is authenticated."

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I've found at the moment is to change the date to the past by a year. For example today's date is 2ndJune2017, if you change the date to **2ndJune2017** and open Vs 2017 RC version, it should work.

I won't consider this as a proper fix but its the only solution worked for me.

Comment: It probably stopped working because VS 2017 has already been released and you shouldn't be using the RC anymore