# License for Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise or Professional for Preview editions expires, contrary to the EULA or instructions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

This issue is about that VS2017 Preview stops working, seemingly because of a license issue, but it's a scenario that I believe is supported and behavior of VS is in error; this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390466/visual-studio-community-2017-is-a-30-day-trial).

While Microsoft writes *["We strongly recommend"](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/)* that you use the same version you have a license for, that text does not exclude that scenario. The [EULA](https://www.visualstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Visual-Studio-2017-Licensing-Whitepaper-March-2017.pdf) allows to use it until it becomes RTM.

However, my Visual Studio Enterprise Preview (15.5 P1) now says that the trial license is expired, and while it has a button to renew that trial, that seems to have no effect.

So, I've tried the following (I believe, all legal):

- Create a new account (as suggested by Microsoft on some forums): same message
- Check in Downloads section of my account: it shows the preview editions just fine.
- Find some way to add a Trial License or subscription, nothing found
- Follow [Microsoft's own suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/9166/cant-renew-trial-license.html) to refresh account info by deleting some settings and restarting, same message.

The error message I see:

> *We could not unlock Visual Studio with the accounts available. Please ensure that you have added an account with a valid subscription and the account is authenticated.*

[image]

And in my subscriptions page it says that no key is required, it doesn't say the license has ended:

[image]

Comment: I don't mind people voting this down, but can you elaborate? I already said in my intro that if this question should not be asked here you should vote to Close, but these related questions, with many upvotes, suggests this is the right place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390466/visual-studio-community-2017-is-a-30-day-trial and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722168/visual-studio-2017-rc-prerelease-has-ended?rq=1

Comment: @Machavity, I understand, but this is not about licensing advice (I know what license I have and what I want already), it is about understanding what happened here, i.e., bug or misconfiguration, or wrong understanding of the process. But as can be seen by my answer, contrary to Microsoft's instructions on the Preview-page, this scenario is not possible anymore since VS2017. See also the linked answers, they are much more on the "licensing advice" topic, imo (perhaps they should be moved too?). Either way, if it should be moved, it should be moved ;).

Comment: I actually started a [Meta on it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358439/are-visual-studio-licensing-questions-on-topic-or-not) because I had some second thoughts. If they OK it I'll withdraw the close vote.

Comment: I agree it's an edge case. Maybe I should reword it somehow. Just did. Hope it's clearer now and more in line with on topic guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[(I did receive an answer from Microsoft after posting again)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/137611/after-installing-enterprise-2017-rtm-trial-license.html)*

Bottom line is: in their EULA they do not forbid this scenario, and on the [Preview Editions](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/) page, they only say *"we do not recommend it"*, but as the [answer from Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/137827/view.html) shows, it is not only not recommended, it is simply not possible.

So:

- if you use Enterprise Preview then the Trial License is shared with the RTM License for the same product (even though they are physically different licenses).
- Whether or not you have the RTM product installed, the license for Preview will expire
- If you use Professional Preview, the same.
- A Professional License is not valid to test-drive Enterprise Preview.
- Having no license at all means: you can only use Preview until the license expires.

Bottom line: after the trial period, you are stuck with Community Preview. In other words, if you want to help Microsoft getting rid of their bugs in Enterprise or Professional by diligently installing the Preview editions, you have to pay [$539/year (Professional) or $2999/year (Enterprise)](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/).

Note that this rule is not enforced legally, as legally you can use the Preview edition until the Preview edition becomes an RTM edition (i.e., VS2017 15.5 Preview 1, 2 etc, until 15.5 becomes RTM). Practically, they prevent it, though.

If you are an OSS developer, even for Microsoft-owned products such as Paket or F#, you cannot test your products with Preview editions of Professional or Enterprise, until you decide to buy them (but for most OSS developers, that price may be too steep). This is unfortunate, as the plugin/addon system for Community and Professional is quite different.